# Reading and recording streaming over rtsp python

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I want to build a web application that read rtsp streaming via opencv and dispay it in web browser. Also i have a button to trigger recording action which will save the video from rtsp streaming from this moment until i hit another button to stop recording.

For streaming over rtsp protocol, i am currently referring to this resource: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/

Could you please suggest me some ways to do this effectively?